# HTTP GET request in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http-get, dashcode

I need to do an [HTTP GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request in JavaScript. What's the best way to do that?

I need to do this in a Mac OS X dashcode widget.

Comment: Note that this is subject to the Same Origin Policy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: the answers to this question are like a history lesson

Answer (score 1472, accepted):

Browsers (and Dashcode) provide an XMLHttpRequest object which can be used to make HTTP requests from JavaScript:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

However, synchronous requests are discouraged and will generate a warning along the lines of:

> Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), **synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated** due to the negative effects to the user experience.

You should make an asynchronous request and handle the response inside an event handler.

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: This one is neat, however note that IE 10 pops up a security alert when using this and trying to access url in a different domain than the page's domain

Comment: Well, of course Javascript has it built in, or how could any Javascript library offer a convenience method for it?  The difference being that the convenience methods offer, well, convenience, and a clearer, simpler syntax.

Comment: XML prefix because it uses the X from AJAX ~ [Asynchronous JavaScript and XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).  Also, good point re the "[API that has and ECMAScript binding](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest)" is due to the fact that JavaScript can be in many things, other than browsers supporting HTTP (e.g. like Adobe Reader ...)  Good thing to remember so hats-off to PointedEars.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka: there's a good reason, see [this section of the W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#introduction) where it explains the name. Google is your friend ;)

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Actually all the answers above are off the mark (infact the linked W3 docs explains "each component of this name is potentially misleading"). Correct answer? its just badly named http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067185/why-is-it-called-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Caution: with this function your callback will never be called back if the page responds to anything but status 200 OK.

Comment: How come this triggers CORS? I thought GET requests weren't supposed to trigger it?

Comment: For example are characters like >> & << encoded to %26 ??

Comment: @HeroCC — You thought wrong. Any cross-origin ajax request is subject to the same origin policy.

Comment: why do we need to `xmlHttp.send(null);`. what does it mean?

Comment: what if the code is called in $.ajax? is synchronous still deprecated?

Comment: The [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)  offers a better way to do this, and can be polyfilled when necessary (see @PeterGibson's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297729/9069356)).

Answer (score 278):

[`window.fetch`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch?hl=en) is a modern replacement for `XMLHttpRequest` that makes use of ES6 promises. There's a nice explanation [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/), but it boils down to (from the article):

```
fetch(url).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
});
```

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) has been good since 2017. IE will likely not get official support. [GitHub has a polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) available adds support to some legacy browsers (esp versions of Safari pre March 2017 and mobile browsers from the same period).

I guess whether this is more convenient than jQuery or XMLHttpRequest or not depends on the nature of the project.

Here's a link to the spec https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/

**Edit**:

Using ES7 async/await, this becomes simply (based on [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/msmfsd/fca50ab095b795eb39739e8c4357a808)):

```
async function fetchAsync (url) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

Comment: I might save someone some time by mentioning that you can do this to include credentials in the request: `fetch(url, { credentials:"include" })`

Comment: @bugmenot123 `window.fetch` doesn't come with an XML parser, but you can parse the response yourself if you handle it as text (not json as in the example above). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37702056/66349 for an example

Comment: Beware that `response.json()` here only returns a `Promise`, not the parsed response payload, hence the need for `return response.json();}).then(function(data) {...`

Comment: why response .then called afterwards? isn't enough for the response only? @PeterGibson

Comment: Your update is the simplest method for me. Thanks for that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/

Comment: Actually you should call catch before then, so that you handle everything inside then.

Answer (score 214):

[In jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get(
    "somepage.php",
    {paramOne : 1, paramX : 'abc'},
    function(data) {
       alert('page content: ' + data);
    }
);
```

Comment: note that this isn't working in IE 10 when trying to access url in a different domain than the page's domain

Comment: @BornToCode you should investigate further and possibly open up a bug on the jQuery issue tracker in that case

Comment: I know some people want to write pure Javascript.  I get that.  I have no problem with people doing that in their projects.  My "In jQuery:" should be intpreted as "I know you asked how to do it in Javascript, but let me show you how you would do that with jQuery, that you might have your curiosity piqued by seeing what kind of syntax conciseness and clarity you can enjoy by using this library, which would afford you numerous other advantages and tools as well".

Comment: Observe also that the original poster later said: "Thanks for all the answers! I went with jQuery based on some things I read on their site.".

Answer (score 181):

Lots of great advice above, but not very reusable, and too often filled with DOM nonsense and other fluff that hides the easy code.

Here's a Javascript class we created that's reusable and easy to use.  Currently it only has a GET method, but that works for us.  Adding a POST shouldn't tax anyone's skills.

```
var HttpClient = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }

        anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send( null );
    }
}
```

Using it is as easy as:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.get('http://some/thing?with=arguments', function(response) {
    // do something with response
});
```

Comment: UnCaughtReference error, HttpClient is not defined . I am getting this one first line it self .

Comment: How do you call it from html onClick?

Comment: Make a function else where that contains the var client... and just run functionName(); return false; in the onClick

Comment: `ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined`

Answer (score 102):

A version without callback

```
var i = document.createElement("img");
i.src = "/your/GET/url?params=here";
```

Comment: Excellent! I needed a Greasemonkey script to keep a session alive and this snippet is perfect. Just wrapped it in an `setInterval` call.

Comment: how do I get the result?

Comment: @user4421975 You don't get - to get access to request response, you need to use aforementioned XMLHttpRequest instead.

Comment: I think we can even do without JS `<img src="/your/GET/url?params=here">`

Comment: @OMRYVOLK that's the neat part, you don't

Answer (score 76):

Here is code to do it directly with JavaScript. But, as previously mentioned, you'd be much better off with a JavaScript library. My favorite is jQuery.

In the case below, an ASPX page (that's servicing as a poor man's REST service) is being called to return a JavaScript JSON object.

```
var xmlHttp = null;

function GetCustomerInfo()
{
    var CustomerNumber = document.getElementById( "TextBoxCustomerNumber" ).value;
    var Url = "GetCustomerInfoAsJson.aspx?number=" + CustomerNumber;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", Url, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
}

function ProcessRequest() 
{
    if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 ) 
    {
        if ( xmlHttp.responseText == "Not found" ) 
        {
            document.getElementById( "TextBoxCustomerName"    ).value = "Not found";
            document.getElementById( "TextBoxCustomerAddress" ).value = "";
        }
        else
        {
            var info = eval ( "(" + xmlHttp.responseText + ")" );

            // No parsing necessary with JSON!        
            document.getElementById( "TextBoxCustomerName"    ).value = info.jsonData[ 0 ].cmname;
            document.getElementById( "TextBoxCustomerAddress" ).value = info.jsonData[ 0 ].cmaddr1;
        }                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this answer is one of the top results for googling "http request javascript", it's worth mentioning that running eval on the response data like that is considered bad practice

Comment: @Kloar good point, but it would be even better to give the reason why it's bad, which I guess is security.
Explaining why practices are bad is the best way to make people switch their habits.

Answer (score 62):

> A copy-paste modern version *( using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) )* :

```
//Option with catch
fetch( textURL )
   .then(async r=> console.log(await r.text()))
   .catch(e=>console.error('Boo...' + e));

//No fear...
(async () =>
    console.log(
            (await (await fetch( jsonURL )).json())
            )
)();
```

> A copy-paste classic version:

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            document.body.className = 'ok';
            console.log(this.responseText);
        } else if (this.response == null && this.status === 0) {
            document.body.className = 'error offline';
            console.log("The computer appears to be offline.");
        } else {
            document.body.className = 'error';
        }
    }
};
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send(null);
```

Answer (score 47):

**Short and clean:**

```js
const http = new XMLHttpRequest()

http.open("GET", "https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/toto/africa")
http.send()

http.onload = () => console.log(http.responseText)
```

Comment: What does that last line, specifically the `= () =>` do?

Comment: Last line defines a callback function, to execute when server respose is loaded.

Answer (score 26):

**Modern, clean and shortest**

```
fetch('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=1')
```

```js
let url = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=1&start-with-lorem=2';

// to only send GET request without waiting for response just call 
fetch(url);

// to wait for results use 'then'
fetch(url).then(r=> r.json().then(j=> console.log('\nREQUEST 2',j)));

// or async/await
(async()=> 
  console.log('\nREQUEST 3', await(await fetch(url)).json()) 
)();
```

```html
Open Chrome console network tab to see request
```

Comment: Should be mentioned `fetch` not supported by any IE - [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#browser_compatibility) (if anyone cares about IE in 2021)

Comment: 2021: what is IE?

Answer (score 23):

IE will cache URLs in order to make loading faster, but if you're, say, polling a server at intervals trying to get new information, IE will cache that URL and will likely return the same data set you've always had.

Regardless of how you end up doing your GET request - vanilla JavaScript, Prototype, jQuery, etc - make sure that you put a mechanism in place to combat caching. In order to combat that, append a unique token to the end of the URL you're going to be hitting. This can be done by:

```
var sURL = '/your/url.html?' + (new Date()).getTime();
```

This will append a unique timestamp to the end of the URL and will prevent any caching from happening.

Answer (score 14):

[Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org) makes it dead simple

```
new Ajax.Request( '/myurl', {
  method:  'get',
  parameters:  { 'param1': 'value1'},
  onSuccess:  function(response){
    alert(response.responseText);
  },
  onFailure:  function(){
    alert('ERROR');
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that Mac OS X doesn't come with Prototype pre-installed. As the widget needs to run in any computer, including Prototype (or jQuery) in each widget is not the best solution.

Comment: @kiamlaluno use Prototype cdn from cloudflare

Answer (score 13):

One solution supporting older browsers:

```
function httpRequest() {
    var ajax = null,
        response = null,
        self = this;

    this.method = null;
    this.url = null;
    this.async = true;
    this.data = null;

    this.send = function() {
        ajax.open(this.method, this.url, this.asnyc);
        ajax.send(this.data);
    };

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
        }
        catch(e) {
            try {
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
            }
            catch(error) {
                self.fail("not supported");
            }
        }
    }

    if(ajax == null) {
        return false;
    }

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4) {
            if(this.status == 200) {
                self.success(this.responseText);
            }
            else {
                self.fail(this.status + " - " + this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Maybe somewhat overkill but you definitely go safe with this code.

**Usage:**

```
//create request with its porperties
var request = new httpRequest();
request.method = "GET";
request.url = "https://example.com/api?parameter=value";

//create callback for success containing the response
request.success = function(response) {
    console.log(response);
};

//and a fail callback containing the error
request.fail = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
};

//and finally send it away
request.send();
```

Comment: Could people please give some comments about what I have done wrong? Not very helpful in that way!

Comment: The best answer in my opinion, if one is coding in ES5 using plain javascript.

Comment: @CoderX nobody is coding in plain ES5 JavaScript any more these days. We have very good transpilers like Babel for that.

Answer (score 11):

To do this Fetch API is the recommended approach, using JavaScript Promises. XMLHttpRequest (XHR), IFrame object or dynamic `<script>` tags are older (and clunkier) approaches.

```
<script type=“text/javascript”> 
    // Create request object 
    var request = new Request('https://example.com/api/...', 
         { method: 'POST', 
           body: {'name': 'Klaus'}, 
           headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) 
         });
    // Now use it! 

   fetch(request) 
   .then(resp => { 
         // handle response 
   }) 
   .catch(err => { 
         // handle errors 
    });
</script>
```

Here is a great [fetch demo](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data) and [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not familiar with Mac OS Dashcode Widgets, but if they let you use JavaScript libraries and support [XMLHttpRequests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest), I'd use [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#examples) and do something like this:

```
var page_content;
$.get( "somepage.php", function(data){
    page_content = data;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

### SET OF FUNCTIONS RECIPES EASY AND SIMPLE

I prepared a set of functions that are somehow similar but yet demonstrate new functionality as well as the simplicity that Javascript has reached if you know how to take advantage of it.

---

0. Let some basic constants

---

```js
let data;
const URLAPI = "https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users";
function setData(dt) {
    data = dt;
}
```

---

1. Most simple

---

```js
// MOST SIMPLE ONE 
function makeRequest1() {       
    fetch(URLAPI)
        .then(response => response.json()).then( json => setData(json))
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => {
            console.log("Data received 1 --> ", data);
            data = null;
    });
}
```

---

2. Variations using Promises and Async facilities

---

```js
// ASYNC FUNCTIONS 
function makeRequest2() { 
    fetch(URLAPI)
        .then(async response => await response.json()).then(async json => await setData(json))
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => {
            console.log("Data received 2 --> ", data);
            data = null;            
        });
}

function makeRequest3() {    
    fetch(URLAPI)
        .then(async response => await response.json()).then(json => setData(json))
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => {
            console.log("Data received 3 --> ", data);
            data = null;
        });
}

// Better Promise usages
function makeRequest4() {
    const response = Promise.resolve(fetch(URLAPI).then(response => response.json())).then(json => setData(json) ).finally(()=> {
        console.log("Data received 4 --> ", data);

    })
}
```

---

3. Demostration of one liner function!!!

---

```js
// ONE LINER STRIKE ASYNC WRAPPER FUNCTION 
async function makeRequest5() {
    console.log("Data received 5 -->", await Promise.resolve(fetch(URLAPI).then(response => response.json().then(json => json ))) );
}
```

***WORTH MENTION ---> [@Daniel De León](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25358151/13903942) propably the cleanest function****

```js
(async () =>
    console.log(
            (await (await fetch( URLAPI )).json())
            )
)();
```

---

4. The top answer -> [By @tggagne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22076667/13903942) shows functionality with HttpClient API.

The same can be achieve with Fetch. As per this [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) by MDN  shows  how you can pass a INIT as second argument, basically opening the possibility to configure easily an API with classic methods (get, post...) .

---

```js
// Example POST method implementation:
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

postData('https://example.com/answer', { answer: 42 })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `data.json()` call
  });
```

### Node

**Fetch is not available on Node (*Server Side*)**

The easiest solution (end of 2021) is to use **[Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/example)**.

```js
$ npm install axios
```

Then Run:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const request = async (url) => await (await axios.get( url ));
let response = request(URL).then(resp => console.log(resp.data));
```

Answer (score 6):

In your widget's Info.plist file, don't forget to set your `AllowNetworkAccess` key to true.

Answer (score 6):

You can get an HTTP GET request in two ways:

1. This approach based on xml format. You have to pass the URL for the request.

   ```
   xmlhttp.open("GET","URL",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
   ```
2. This one is based on jQuery. You have to specify the URL and function_name you want to call.

   ```
   $("btn").click(function() {
     $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function_name(result) {
       $("#innerdiv").html(result);
     }});
   });
   ```

Answer (score 6):

For those who use [AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), it's `$http.get`:

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

Now with asynchronous js, we can use this method with the fetch() method to make promises more concisely. Async functions are supported in all modern browsers.

```js
async function funcName(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  var data = await response.json();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to use AJAX (you can find a simple tutorial on this page [Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/%22Tizag%22)). The reason is that any other technique you may use requires more code, it is not guaranteed to work cross browser without rework and requires you to use more client memory by opening hidden pages inside frames passing urls parsing their data and closing them.
AJAX is the way to go in this situation. That is my two years of javascript heavy development speaking.

Answer (score 4):

```
function get(path) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "get");
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}


get('/my/url/')
```

Same thing can be done for post request as well.
Have a look at this link [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Answer (score 4):

To refresh best answer from joann with promise this is my code:

```
let httpRequestAsync = (method, url) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                resolve(xhr.responseText);
            }
            else {
                reject(new Error(xhr.responseText));
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple async request:

```
function get(url, callback) {
  var getRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  getRequest.open("get", url, true);

  getRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if (getRequest.readyState === 4 && getRequest.status === 200) {
      callback(getRequest.responseText);
    }
  });

  getRequest.send();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

You'd be best off using a library such as [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework) or [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

Answer (score 2):

```
// Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
request.open('GET', 'restUrl', true)

request.onload = function () {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
}

// Send request
request.send()
```

Answer (score 2):

In pure javascript and returning a Promise:

```
  httpRequest = (url, method = 'GET') => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url);
      xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status === 200) { resolve(xhr.responseText); }
        else { reject(new Error(xhr.responseText)); }
      };
      xhr.send();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the code for a Dashboard widget, and you don't want to include a JavaScript library in every widget you created, then you can use the object XMLHttpRequest that Safari natively supports.

As reported by Andrew Hedges, a widget doesn't have access to a network, by default; you need to change that setting in the info.plist associated with the widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure JS too:

```
// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
// XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
xhr.open(method, url, true);
} else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
// XDomainRequest for IE.
xhr = new XDomainRequest();
xhr.open(method, url);
} else {
// CORS not supported.
xhr = null;
}
return xhr;
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest() {
 // This is a sample server that supports CORS.
 var url = 'http://html5rocks-cors.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/index.html';

var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
if (!xhr) {
alert('CORS not supported');
return;
}

// Response handlers.
xhr.onload = function() {
var text = xhr.responseText;
alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + text);
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
};

xhr.send();
}
```

See: for more details: [html5rocks tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to xml files to load your files as an object and access properties as an object in a very fast way.

- Attention, so that javascript can interpret the content correctly, it is necessary to save your files in the same format as your HTML page. If you use UTF 8 save your files in UTF8, etc.

XML works as a tree ok? instead of writing

```
     <property> value <property>
```

write a simple file like this:

```
      Property1: value
      Property2: value
      etc.
```

Save your file ..
Now call the function ....

```
    var objectfile = {};

function getfilecontent(url){
    var cli = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    cli.onload = function(){
         if((this.status == 200 || this.status == 0) && this.responseText != null) {
        var r = this.responseText;
        var b=(r.indexOf('\n')?'\n':r.indexOf('\r')?'\r':'');
        if(b.length){
        if(b=='\n'){var j=r.toString().replace(/\r/gi,'');}else{var j=r.toString().replace(/\n/gi,'');}
        r=j.split(b);
        r=r.filter(function(val){if( val == '' || val == NaN || val == undefined || val == null ){return false;}return true;});
        r = r.map(f => f.trim());
        }
        if(r.length > 0){
            for(var i=0; i<r.length; i++){
                var m = r[i].split(':');
                if(m.length>1){
                        var mname = m[0];
                        var n = m.shift();
                        var ivalue = m.join(':');
                        objectfile[mname]=ivalue;
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
cli.open("GET", url);
cli.send();
}
```

now you can get your values efficiently.

```
getfilecontent('mesite.com/mefile.txt');

window.onload = function(){
 
if(objectfile !== null){
alert (objectfile.property1.value);
}
}
```

It's just a small gift to contribute to the group. Thanks for your like :)

If you want to test the function on your PC locally, restart your browser with the following command (supported by all browsers except safari):

```
yournavigator.exe '' --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()"> GET CONTENT</button>

 <script>
        function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "<Enter URL>";``
            xmlhttp.onload = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == "200") {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic fetch request is really simple to set up. Have a look at the following code:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```